# Multithreading issue updating the value

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have difficulty understanding why the multithreading fails to update values before the thread completes. Does the separate thread have its own copy of the references or values?

If not, to my understanding the code below should work properly when MyMethod is called, but often it does not create instances of some MyType objects in the array before the `thread.IsAlive` becomes false:

```
class MyClass
{
    static MyType[] obj = new MyType[Environment.ProcessorCount - 1];
    void MyMethod()
    {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[Environment.ProcessorCount - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount - 1; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(() => FillObjects(i));
            threads[i].Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
            threads[i].Start();
        }

        while (threads[i].Any(c => c.IsAlive))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
    void FillObjects(int i)
    {
        obj[i] = new MyType();
        //perform actions with obj[i] to fill it with necessary values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign the value of the loop variable to a local variable. Otherwise it's possible that the first execution of `FillObjects(i)` is executed after `i` was incremented so `FillObjects(0)` is never called and therefore `obj[0]` is never assigned.

```
void MyMethod()
{
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[Environment.ProcessorCount - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount - 1; i++)
    {
        int local = i;
        threads[i] = new Thread(() => FillObjects(local));
        threads[i].Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
        threads[i].Start();
    }

    while (threads.Any(c => c.IsAlive))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point. If the first statement in `FillObjects()` were a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` probably only `obj[Environment.ProcessorCount - 1]` would be non-null because the loop would have incremented `i` to its end value before the first object is created. Thinking about it, FillObjects() may throw because `i` actually is incremented to `Environment.ProcessorCount-1` before the loop exits and is thus out of bounds of `obj`.

Comment: Thank you for reply, indeed that was one of the major problems, now it instantiates the objects properly. However the thread does not complete all operations properly before it shuts down and does this at random. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've found my own logical mistake, now it works properly.

Answer (score -1):

On a multi processor machine (which you must have) results written to a memory location in one thread may not be visible in another thread due to caching. Use `Thread.VolatileRead` and `Thread.VolatileWrite` read in order to read and write "through" the cache.

Cf. [the chapter on threading in c# 3.0 in a Nutshell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527570-03-19.aspx) for an explanation. (Look for the question "Is it possible for the Wait method to write "False"?". That example is basically your case.)

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is wrong or not applicable of what I said?

Comment: Although not the one that downvoted: I can't think of a scenario to use volatileRead/Write to solve above problem. The referenced problem from C# in nutshell IMHO doesn't match above problem as well as I don't see any caching problems that volatile would solve.

Comment: @Linky Hm. It's two threads both accessing a static variable. One thread "has written" to it (indicated by an event later in that thread). The other thread reads the value which has been written from the perspective of the writing thread and doesn't see the write. Looks to me much like the scenario here.

Comment: Could this be a reason why some threads effectively do not complete all operations before shutting down? I will test it.

Comment: I've found my own logical mistake, now it works properly.

Comment: @Almis What was the error? Care to update your question?

Comment: @Peter Schneider, the answer given by @Linky solved the problem related with multithreading. The second issue was simply a logical mistake in the method `FillObjects` which has nothing to do with multithreading.